# ListFragment addFooterView

Tags: android, android-layout

Hello I have a ListFragment that fetches some data from the net and then uses a renderer to display them. The problem is that if I add a simple TextView like so:

> TextView tv = new TextView(getActivity());

then it works fine, but if I try to add a more complex view then the application freezes.
I have also tried to inflate the view from an xml but no luck.
Basically I am trying to inflate this RelativeLayout:

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" 
    android:background="@color/main_background" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/leave_comment" 
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:textColor="@color/resultlist_title"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="230dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:inputType="textPostalAddress" >

    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="@string/leave_commentbtn"
        android:background="@drawable/venue_post" 
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText1"
        style="@style/list_button" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp" 
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textColor="@color/white"/>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
```

am I missing something? is it not possible to add a relative layout as footer view?

Comment: Could you add the Code where you call `addFooterView()`. It would be good if you could find out where your code freezes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To inflate relative layout you can use:

```
    View my_view= View.inflate(this, R.layout.layout_name, null);
```

hope it will work then you can add it where you want.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to add header and footer in android you can do by this way. I hope this will help  you.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
        LinearLayout listFooterView = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(
                com.demo.list.R.layout.footerview, null);

        LinearLayout listHeaderView = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(
                com.demo.list.R.layout.headerview, null);
        ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(false);
        lv.addFooterView(listFooterView);
        lv.addHeaderView(listHeaderView);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but I have implemented what Bharat suggested